# Turn on or off tag display in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this CSS:

```
div.row{
    display: none;}
  div.login {
    height: 10em;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;}
```

this HTML:

```
<div id="login" class="login">
  <input type="password" style="width: 25%;" placeholder="Please enter your password">
  <button onclick="logincheck()">Login</button>
</div>
<div id ='row' class="row">...</div>
```

and this JS:

```
function logincheck(){

   var pwd = document.getElementById('pw').value;
   var curpwd = 'somevalue';
   if(pwd === curpwd){
     alert('You are now logged in!');
     var mainpage = document.getElementById("row");
     var logger = document.getElementById("login");
     logger.style.display = "none !important";
     mainpage.style.display = "block";

  }else{
      alert('Sorry the password was not recognized, please try again.');
   }
  }
```

Yet my page remains the same after the 'You are now logged in' window. How do I make the login div disappear and make the row div appear? Also, the script works in chrome but now in explorer. Why?

Comment: Your ID on your row div has single quotes on your row HTML element. User double quotes like your class, and fix the spacing of the equals sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `pwd` to the DOM element `#pw`, yet no element has such an ID. Your first step would be to add an ID of `pw` to the `<input>` element.

After this, all you need to do is change your **[`style.display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** value for `logger`. You have the right idea, though please note that a value of `none !important` is invalid in JavaScript. Instead, simply go with `none`. This works, and the **[`!important` declaration](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)** is generally frowned anyway upon due to its maximum level of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**.

In addition to the note about `!important`, please note that it's also bad practice to use inline event handlers such as `onclick=`. I've updated this to use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** in my example:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#login button');
button.addEventListener("click", logincheck);

function logincheck() {
  var pwd = document.getElementById('pw').value;
  var curpwd = 'somevalue';
  
  if (pwd === curpwd) {
    alert('You are now logged in!');
    var mainpage = document.getElementById("row");
    var logger = document.getElementById("login");
    logger.style.display = "none";
    mainpage.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    alert('Sorry the password was not recognized, please try again.');
  }
}
```

```css
div.row {
  display: none;
}

div.login {
  height: 10em;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="login" class="login">
  <input id="pw" type="password" style="width: 25%;" placeholder="Please enter your password">
  <button>Login</button>
</div>

<div id='row' class="row">...</div>
```

Finally, please be aware that all front-end JavaScript is **visible to users**, even when obsfuscated. As such, any visitor to this page will know that the password is `somevalue`. If this is for a secure page, you probably want to make use of a database and proper encryption instead of relying on front-end JavaScript.

Hope this helps :)